# Random walk inside a random walk inside...

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and consider a random walk on it. Let $G'=(V',E')$ be a subgraph consisting of the vertices and edges that are visited by the random walk.

> Question 0: Is there a standard name for $G'$?

Intuitively $G'$ is a thin subgraph, so for instance, even when $G$ is transient, $G'$ can be recurrent.

> Question 1: Is there a counterexample? So, Is there a transient graph $G$ so that $G'$ is transient with positive probability?

I'm also curious to know what happens when one iterates this procedure, $G,G',G'',\dots$. Does it eventually look like a path graph?

> Question 2: What can one say about $G^{(n)}$ as $n\to \infty$?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Question 0: $G'$ is known as the *trace* of the random walk.

Question 1: $G'$ is always recurrent with probability one. This is [a result of Benjamini, Gurel-Gurevich, and Lyons](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1175287760) from 2007.

Question 2: Since $G'$ is recurrent, with probability one we have $G^{(n)}=G'$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I'd like to add that we have another paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508270 with a different proof of the same result.

Also, regarding "Does it eventually look like a path graph?" in another paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0115 (with Benjamini and Schramm) we prove that there are transient graphs for which the trace of a simple random walk does not look like path in the sense that it does not have infinitely many cutpoints.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: The link has been fixed.